# Swift: How to Display Parsed JSON Data in CollectionView inside a TableView?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to display my data as this [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6kmp.png)

My problem is that data displayed inside table view rows are all the same thing, while it should display all data of the array.

This is the code I used to display the collectionView inside the tableView:

```
var onlineNews = ["local", "Economy", "Variety", "international", "sport"]

var storedOffsets = [Int: CGFloat]()

var tableIndexPath: IndexPath!

@IBOutlet var listTableView: UITableView!

var tableIndex: Int = 0

var categoryResults = [JSON]() {
    didSet {
        listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

let requestManager = RequestManager()


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    for i in onlineNews {
        requestManager.categoryList(sectionName: i)
    }
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return onlineNews.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell

    tableIndex = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? NewsTableViewCell else { return }

        tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? NewsTableViewCell else { return }

        storedOffsets[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] = tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return categoryResults.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColCell",
                                                  for: indexPath) as! NewsCollectionViewCell


  cell.contentType.text = categoryResults[indexPath.row]["ContentType"].stringValue **// This is where I get the same values for all table view rows**
    cell.sectionName.text = onlineNews[tableIndex]


    return cell
}
```

I'm sure someone can absolutely help me with this as I know that it takes only a small tweak to make it work, but not sure where.

**Update:**

I have followed a way that I believe should work, which is to declare the JSON array to be like this [[JSON]], and then use categoryResults[collection.tag][indexPath.item]["ContentType"].stringValue to get to the value. However, it gives me "index out of range" message. Do you have any clue how can I solve the issue?

```
var onlineNews = ["local", "Economy", "Variety", "international", "sport"]

var storedOffsets = [Int: CGFloat]()

@IBOutlet var listTableView: UITableView!

var tableIndex: Int = 0

var categoryResults = [[JSON]]() { // updated
    didSet {
        listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

let requestManager = RequestManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    requestManager.resetCategory()

    updateSearchResults()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateSearchResults), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "categoryResultsUpdated"), object: nil)


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    for i in 0..<onlineNews.count {
        requestManager.categoryList(sectionName: onlineNews[i])


    }

}

func updateSearchResults() {
    categoryResults = [requestManager.categoryResults] // updated
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return onlineNews.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell

    tableIndex = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? NewsTableViewCell else { return }

        tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
        tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] ?? 0

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? NewsTableViewCell else { return }

        storedOffsets[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] = tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset


}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categoryResults[collectionView.tag].count // updated
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColCell",
                                                  for: indexPath) as! NewsCollectionViewCell


    cell.contentType.text = categoryResults[collectionView.tag][indexPath.row]["ContentType"].stringValue // updated



    return cell
}
```

This the content of RequestManager class (where I call the API):

```
var categoryResults = [JSON]()

func categoryList(sectionName: String) {

    let url = "http://mobile.example.com/api/Content?MobileRequest=GetCategoryNews&PageNo=1&RowsPerPage=10&Category=\(sectionName)&IssueID=0&Type=online"
    print("this is the url \(url)")

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON{ response in
        if let results = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            let items = JSON(results["Data"]?["OnlineCategoryNews"]! as Any).arrayValue

            self.categoryResults += items

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "categoryResultsUpdated"), object: nil)

        }

    }

}

func resetCategory() {
    categoryResults = []
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

**Update 2:**

And here is the method where the collectionView.tag is assigned. This is added to the tableViewCell class:

```
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate
    <D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>
    (dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row
    collectionView.bounds.size.width = self.bounds.size.width
    collectionView.reloadData()



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection view delegate methods don't know context of their collection view. You should calculate onlineNews index depending on the collectionView instance instead of using indexPath.row, which is internal collection view index path.

Edit: better option (to avoid scrolling and layout issues) is to use single collection view, where cells are grouped in rows. If you don't want to make layout manager, you can achieve such layout by adding small, but very wide separator views between sections

Edit2:

```
cell.contentType.text = categoryResults[indexPath.row]["ContentType"].stringValue
```

uses local indexPath of this collection view. You could assign tag to `tableViewCell.collectionView` with a value of desired categoryResults index. Then you can use this tag as in `categoryResults[collectionView.tag]`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please explain more how and where that index can be used to get the result displayed? I tried different methods such as using collectionView.tag instead of indexPath.row and it didn't work, but not sure how the index can be assigned to display the JSON result. I need some further explanation please.

Comment: I mean I need explanation on how the index can be calculated as you mentioned to help getting the JSON result.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I have made changes to my code but I got an index out of range error. Please help me solve this.. I have indicated where I made the changes by adding comments.

Comment: And one more thing I need to tell you. Regarding the point where you mentioned that I need to assign the collectionView.tag. It is already assigned in a different way inside the the tableViewCell class. I will update my question with that method now.

Comment: Where and when do you have index out of range error? In numberOfItemsInSection or cellForItemAt, indexing by collectionView.tag or indexPath.row and when?

Comment: In numberOfItemsInSection, in this particular line: return categoryResults[collectionView.tag].count

Comment: then onlineNews.count is probably bigger than categoryResults.count you are assigning tags from 0 to onlineNews.count-1 in willDisplay. Either you want to return categoryResults.count in numberOfRowsInSection or add empty stubs to categoryResults to display empty collection views in rows where tag >= categoryResults.count and < onlineNews.count

Comment: I followed the first option (returning categoryResults.count in numberOfRowsInSection). It is now "partially" displayed correctly. In the first row I get only one collection view item (it should be 10), the next three rows display all the items correctly, and the last row is totally empty. Any clue why?

Comment: Can you check if categoryResults[0].count is actually 10 and not 1? Also what are categoryResults[0][1]["ContentType"] and what are categoryResults[last_index_here].count and contents?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is working perfectly now! I have figured out that the last issue I found was because of missing data in the JSON URL and it has nothing to do with my code. Many thanks again for your great help!